# How to transpose a XML table with T-SQL XQuery?

Tags: t-sql, xquery

Let's say we have the following XML:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <column>row 1 col 1</column>
    <column>row 1 col 2</column>
    <column>row 1 col 3</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 2 col 1</column>
    <column>row 2 col 2</column>
    <column>row 2 col 3</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 3 col 1</column>
    <column>row 3 col 2</column>
    <column>row 3 col 3</column>
  </row>
</root>
```

How do I transpose this, using **T-SQL XQuery** to:

```
<root>
    <column>
        <row>row 1 col 1</row>
        <row>row 2 col 1</row>
        <row>row 3 col 1</row>
    </column>
    <column>
        <row>row 1 col 2</row>
        <row>row 2 col 2</row>
        <row>row 3 col 2</row>
    </column>
    <column>
        <row>row 1 col 3</row>
        <row>row 2 col 3</row>
        <row>row 3 col 3</row>
    </column>
</root>
```

Comment: Are there always three rows & columns, or do you want it to work with an arbitrary number?

Comment: @AalashM it would be best if it could work in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there might be a really nice approach using `PIVOT`, but I don't know it well enough to be able to say for sure. What I offer here works. I have split it up into chunks for better formatting and to provide commentary:

To start with let's capture the example data

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @x3 xml

SET @x3 = '
<root>
  <row>
    <column>row 1 col 1</column>
    <column>row 1 col 2</column>
    <column>row 1 col 3</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 2 col 1</column>
    <column>row 2 col 2</column>
    <column>row 2 col 3</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 3 col 1</column>
    <column>row 3 col 2</column>
    <column>row 3 col 3</column>
  </row>
</root>
'

DECLARE @x xml
SET @x = @x3

-- @x is now our input
```

Now the actual transposing code:

Establish the size of the matrix:

```
WITH Size(Size) AS
(
    SELECT CAST(SQRT(COUNT(*)) AS int) 
    FROM @x.nodes('/root/row/column') T(C)
)
```

Shred the data, use `ROW_NUMBER` to capture the index (the `-1` is to make it zero based), and use modulo and integer divide on the index to work out the *new* row and column numbers:

```
,Flattened(NewRow, NewCol, Value) AS
(
    SELECT
        -- i/@size as old_r, i % @size as old_c, 
        i % (SELECT TOP 1 Size FROM Size) AS NewRow, 
        i / (SELECT TOP 1 Size FROM Size) AS NewCol, 
        Value
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C)) - 1 AS i, 
            C.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Value
        FROM @x.nodes('/root/row/column') T(C)
        ) ShreddedInput
)
```

With this CTE `FlattenedInput` available, all we now need to do is get the `FOR XML` options and query structure right and we're done:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT Value 'column'
        FROM
            Flattened t_inner
        WHERE
            t_inner.NewRow = t_outer.NewRow
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ) row
FROM
    Flattened t_outer
GROUP BY NewRow
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('root')
```

Sample output:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <column>row 1 col 1</column>
    <column>row 2 col 1</column>
    <column>row 3 col 1</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 1 col 2</column>
    <column>row 2 col 2</column>
    <column>row 3 col 2</column>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column>row 1 col 3</column>
    <column>row 2 col 3</column>
    <column>row 3 col 3</column>
  </row>
</root>
```

Works on any size 'square' data. Note the lack of sanity checking / error handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @x3 = ' 
<root> 
  <row> 
    <column>row 1 col 1</column> 
    <column>row 1 col 2</column> 
    <column>row 1 col 3</column> 
  </row> 
  <row> 
    <column>row 2 col 1</column> 
    <column>row 2 col 2</column> 
    <column>row 2 col 3</column> 
  </row> 
  <row> 
    <column>row 3 col 1</column> 
    <column>row 3 col 2</column> 
    <column>row 3 col 3</column> 
  </row> 
</root> 
' 

select @x3 = replace(@x3,'<row>','<rowtemp>')
select @x3 = replace(@x3,'<column>','<row>')
select @x3 = replace(@x3,'<rowtemp>','<column>')

select @x3
```